# How to programmatically get string that will be voiced by talkback(accessibility) in Android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility

Help me please. I need to programmatically somehow get a string that will be announced using Talkback when hovering over a focus element, I was looking for ways to get this string in such classes - AccessibilityRecord , AccessibilityEvent , AccessibilityNodeInfo , but I didn’t find it (maybe I didn’t look carefully).
For example, in the screenshot, the focus is on the "DONE" button, it will be voiced "DONE, Button. Double-tap to active." (The text that is spoken is written from the bottom of the screen in toast, this toast was enabled in the developer options), and I need to somehow get the voiced string as a program object (String). How can i do this?

[First screen (first part of voice acting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Vwv.jpg)

[Second screen (second part of voice acting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdFv5.jpg)

I was looking for ways to get this string in such classes - AccessibilityRecord , AccessibilityEvent , AccessibilityNodeInfo , but I didn’t find it (maybe I didn’t look carefully).

Comment: You want to get the text that Talkback speaks? I'm not sure if that's available. What would you do with it? In general, when a screen reader (whether Talkback, VoiceOver [iOS], NVDA [pc], etc) announces an element, it will say the element's name (usually called the accessible name) which is the label for a button, the value or state of an element (not required for a button but makes sense for a checkbox [checked}), and an optional description. Then a screen reader might also say whether to "double tap" to select the element. It all depends on the user's screen reader settings.

Comment: Yes, i want get text that Talkback speaks. I want to try to make a library with which it will be possible to write automatic tests to check the correctness of the accessibility, but for this I need to somehow get the string that will be voiced by Talkback

Comment: Your automatic tests should calculate the name, role, and value of the element since that is what the screen reader will announce.

Answer (score 0):

The xml element contentdescription deals with screen reader speakable text.  Set this element